# Handle two requests on two server to validate data at the same time

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-restcontroller

I have a spring restcontroller which is deployed on two server and load balancer is handling the request. There is one api which validates some data on the basis of input. Now there are some cases where two requests came with same input but on two different server at the same time and validated the same data which should be happened. One API request should validate one data only.
How to handle such type of cases. I changed the status once data is validated but in this case this is not happening as request is coming at the same time.

Comment: You need to use some kind of locking. I suggest you to read about optimistic locking. If you using `Hibernate` it is very easy to enable.

Comment: I am not using hibernate

Comment: You still can do that, just need more work.